# Issues when using inverse/forward search with vim and xdvi (linux)

Tags: vim, linux, forward-inverse-search

I am using vim 7.3.35 with the vim-latexsuite on ubuntu. After googling around I managed to setup forward/inverse search with `xdvi` by adding the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex --interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials $*'
let g:Tex_ViewRuleComplete_dvi = 'xdvi -s 8 -keep -editor "gvim --servername vimlatex --remote +\%l \%f" $* &'
```

(I run vim on `tex` files as `vim --servername vimlatex myfile.tex` so that I do not get different instances of vim on the inverse search)

The above lines work fine except for two cases:

1. If at any part of the path to my `tex` file there is a space character
2. If my `tex` file name contains a dot

In the fist case, if I compile the file `"a b.tex"` and try to view it with `xdvi` I will get the error:

> xdvi.bin: Error: Unrecognized option `b.tex'

In the second case, it will compile but when `xdvi` opens I get a warning dialog:

> No references to source file "myfile.tex" in DVI file.

I assume it has to do with the way those lines in my `.vimrc` are written. Any ideas how I could work around that so that I can use space and dots in my paths?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with xdvi. Did you find a way to get around it? I am okay with not having spaces with my file names or directories but the warning is really annoying. Inverse search works without a problem but I am not able to do forward search.

Comment: Yes, that's the "solution": no spaces in the file name AND path. If that is the case I do not get any warnings. So you have no spaces whatsoever and you still get a warning?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to fix the problem. I was not giving xdvi the correct arguments for sourceposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many parts of the TeX 'tool chain' do not support spaces in file names/paths. While there are workarounds for some of the cases, that is not always possible. As such, the best approach here is not to have any relative or absolute paths in use which include spaces.

Comment: Thanks for bumping this up, I was still wondering about it.